# Failure in setting up Sparkpost for outgoing mail

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

I've created a sending and bounce domain on Sparkpost, ccrmmail.vietfeir.com. This domain has been verified by Sparkpost. I have an api key with all grants. When I try to save and send, I get this error:

```
Could not check status for domain vietfeir.com (Exception Sparkpost error: Permission denied. Check that the API key is authorized for request https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/sending-domains/vietfeir.com.).
```

How can I configure this correctly to use ccrmmail.vietfeir.com instead of just vietfeir.com?

Answer (score 2):

I got Sparkpost support to help me with this. I needed to add a DKIM TXT entry in my DNS for vietfeir.com and generate a new API key.

Comment: Just a note about Sparkpost. I was doing testing of bounces for a new site and hit a high bounce threshold and was suspended by Sparkpost. I couldn't convince their compliance checking folks that this was intentional and not because of a dirty list. For my testing, I only use two email addresses so if I force one to bounce, the bounce rate for that mailing will naturally be 50%.